# unspecified column being added to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite3-python

I am accessing my brokers API and
downloading my open positions in derivatives and storing in a database.
what I cant understand is - when the table portfolio_position is created an unspecified column called 'Unnamed : 0 ' is added.  The last part of the code is the print output of the created table.

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\ronny\\breeze_venv\\training')
  
with open ("position.txt" , "r") as file :
    contents = str(file.read())
    post_contents = contents[31:]
    pre_contents = '{\'Success\': [{\'date\':\'\',\'segment\':\'fno\','
    final = pre_contents + post_contents
    file.close()
    d = ast.literal_eval(final)


new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['Success'])
connection = sqlite3.connect('portfolio.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
new.to_csv('data.csv' ,columns=['date','segment','product_type','stock_code','expiry_date','strike_price','right','action','quantity','average_price','ltp','price','stock_index_indicator','underlying'])
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 

try :
    df.to_sql('portfolio_position', connection ,if_exists='append', index = 'False')
except :
    df.to_sql('portfolio_position', connection ,if_exists='replace', index = 'False')

connection.commit()

c = cursor.execute('select * from portfolio_position')
names = [description[0] for description in c.description]
connection.close()
print(names)

['False', 'Unnamed: 0', 'date', 'segment', 'product_type', 'stock_code', 'expiry_date', 'strike_price', 'right', 'action', 'quantity', 'average_price', 'ltp', 'price', 'stock_index_indicator', 'underlying']
```

Comment: It must be `index=False` in `to_sql`, not a string `'False'`.

Comment: Provide a sample of the contents `data.csv` which can [reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The part of the code before `connection = sqlite3.connect('portfolio.db')` is irrelevant. Or start with an example of `d['Success']` used to create the CSV. Read this post on [how to provide a **good pandas example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391).